# Thymeleaf & AJAX mapping JSON data

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring-Boot project using Thymeleaf.

The HTML form has groups of fields for inputting personal details like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnGetPerson"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
<Input type="text" id="id0" name="id" th:field="*{person[0].id}" />
<Input type="text" name="surname" th:field="*{person[0].surname}" />
<Input type="text" name="firstname" th:field="*{person[0].firstname}" />
...
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnGetPerson"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
<Input type="text" id="id1" name="id" th:field="*{person[1].id}" />
<Input type="text" name="surname" th:field"=*{person[1].surname}" />
<Input type="text" name=firstname" th:field="*{person[1].firstname}" />
etc
```

The results are coming back from the server correctly as JSON and look like:

```
surname : Smith
firstname: Bob
```

Then in the script file I got as far as:

```
    // GET AND RETURN PERSON
$( '#btnGetPerson').click(function() {
    var $theForm = $(this).closest('.panel-body');
    $.get('/person/' +$('#id0').val(), function(result) {
        $theForm.find('input[name="surname"]').val(result.surname);
    });
});
```

I was then going to do something like:

```
Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
$('[name="' + key + '"]').val(result[key]);
});
```

To iterate over the keys and values in the JSON - but Thymeleaf renames the name fields in the HTML to match the form backing object, so my name="surname" gets over written with name="event.person[0].surname" where event is the backing object.

How should I approach mapping getting the JSON data that comes back from the server into the DOM?

**UPDATE**

A sample of the rendered html looks like:

```
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Victim / Subject</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">


                        <div class="row">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control hidden" id="personId0" name="persons[0].id" value="1" />
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <label for="surname0" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Surname</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname0" placeholder="surname" name="persons[0].surname" value="EASTWOOD"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div
```

I should also add that the form initially renders with three people (index 0,1,2) and then there is a button to add another set of people fields dynamically by cloning the html fragment.

Comment: Note - I dont want to really use a result div block - I would rather split the JSON key value pairs off to the respective inputs.

Comment: Do you really want to use th:field? "Note - I dont want to really use a result div block"

Comment: As opposed to what other thymeleaf?

Comment: th:value="${value}"

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same ID (ie `btnGetPerson`). Don't do that

Comment: Do you want a button that pops a form in an overlay to insert the data or a form that appends itself to the end of the current div?

Comment: "[...] Thymeleaf renames the name fields in the HTML to match the form backing object, so my name="surname" gets over written with name="event.person[0].surname" where event is the backing object."

So your example isn't complete.  Try sharing the actual rendered HTML so we can actually see what it looks like.

Comment: @xxLITxx I still need the html fields to be bound to the backing object - this only happens with th:field doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON data coming back from server looks like:

```
{  
"id":1,
"surname":"EASTWOOD",
"middlename":"James",
"firstname":"Clint",
"countryOfBirth":"US",
"occupation":"Actor",
"gender":"Male",
"phoneHome":"555-1234",
"dob":"1965-06-17"
}
```

Map this to inputs, but the name and id's are renamed by thymeleaf. So in order to get around this use data-property field with names that match the key names in the JSON. So html inputs look like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control  person" data-property="surname" placeholder="surname" th:field="*{persons[0].surname}"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control  person" data-property="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" th:field="*{persons[0].firstname}"/>
<select class="selectpicker form-control person" data-property="countryOfBirth" data-live-search="true" title="Birth Country" th:field="*{persons[0].countryOfBirth}">
```

Now the data-property provides tags that match the JSON names.

The jquery and javascript to find the closest panel-body and then update the inputs is below. **Note** that because of the way dropdowns are displayed in twitter-bootstrap as buttons I had to find a different class:

```
// GET AND RETURN PERSON
$( '#btnGetPerson').click(function() {
    var $theForm = $(this).closest('.panel-body');
    $.get('/person/' +$('#nia0').val(), function(result) {

        // LOOPS OVER THE PERSON INPUTS
        $theForm.find('.form-control.person').each(function()  {
            var formkey = $(this).attr('data-property');
            $(this).val(result[formkey]);
        });

        // LOOPS OVER THE SELECT PICKERS
        $theForm.find('.bootstrap-select').each(function() {
            var formkey = $(this).find('.selectpicker.form-control').attr('data-property');
            $(this).find('.filter-option').text(result[formkey]);
            $(this).find('.filter-option').val(result[formkey]);
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks to all those that helped.

Hope this helps someone else.